# I need something like JFileChooser that provides the UI skeleton but has nothing to do with File

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jfilechooser

I need to provide a java widget that provides users with a subset of the controls that a JFilechooser provides. Specifically I need to provide the look and feel of a JFileChooser dialog for the following typical actions:

- Save Action
- Load Action

But I am allowing them to see and do only the following:

1. See a static list of names that has nothing to do with File objects (These are names pulled from a mysql table).
2. Change the name so it doesn't conflict with a name they can see from within the static list.
3. Select a name from the static list
4. Ok
5. Cancel

So really just a way to do the basic things you can do with a JFileChooser minus the directory navigation and creation. Does such a skeleton of the JFileChooser exist or do I need to create this from scratch?

Thanks.

-Dennis

Comment: I think if you are only interested in L&F it would be better to create one from scratch, the other option is subclassing JFileChooser but you will be fighting against the code only to make it do two things.

Comment: I agree. I wanted to see if there was some class I had overlooked meant for this purpose. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Like all Swing components, JFileChooser uses a model, in this case a [FileSystemView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html).  In theory, you can create your own subclass of FileSystemView and pass it to the JFileChooser constructor.  Remember, even though FileSystemView uses File objects, a File instance doesn't have to represent an actual file.

Comment: So really you are suggesting just using the file object such that I'm giving it abstract names, then turn around and use the most basic of methods getName(). Perhaps this could work. I'll have to look at JFileChooser to see if I can hide aspects of the widget that won't apply. Thanks.